# VPN from OpenVPN connects, but can't open some websites on linux, but it works on windows. But all work when I connect to my phone network

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Hi I faced with strange problem related with network.

Context:
I can work on Windows without any restrictions, but I want to setup linux. Today I discovered that vpn works properly when I connect to my phone via hotspot and mobile network. But when I connect to my home network wifi - the weirdness begins.

1. I connected to vpn successfully
2. In terminal ping and traceroute work
3. I can't open some websites and resources in network. For example I can't pass authentication via google or open reddit.com
4. On the windows all work.
5. I told with vpn server's admins and they don't have any restrictions about clients on server.

So I created a [discussion](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3-linux/discussions/205) on github in the linux openvpn3 repo. There some traceroute, ping, iptrables, and dns resolve output.
In conclusion openvpn3 client works properly and the problem on my side. But, as I mentions before, on windows all work without problem

It seems there problem with my provider or router. I can't understand the way where I should dig.

A little updating to my question.

- I use Ubuntu 22.04.1 with 6.2.0-31-generic kernel.
- Well it's a work vpn from company which doesn't support linux, but it's ok if I find a solution. I told with admins there no any restrictions to linux on server.
- I will plan to test it with direct Ethernet cable
- `resolvectl dns` before connect to vpn:

```
   global: 8.8.8.8 81.95.225.252 81.95.225.253

    Link 2 (wlp0s20f3): 192.168.1.1
    Link 3 (outline-tun0):
    Link 4 (br-46c07f55586b):
    Link 5 (br-602d2c7126c0):
    Link 6 (br-97e9a873d9ef):
    Link 7 (br-ad2ab74554bb):
    Link 8 (br-b57ce470a7a5):
    Link 9 (docker0):
    Link 10 (br-366dd99965dd):
```

- `resolvectl dns` after connect to vpn:

```
    Global: 8.8.8.8 81.95.225.252 81.95.225.253
    Link 2 (wlp0s20f3): 192.168.1.1
    Link 3 (outline-tun0):
    Link 4 (br-46c07f55586b):
    Link 5 (br-602d2c7126c0):
    Link 6 (br-97e9a873d9ef):
    Link 7 (br-ad2ab74554bb):
    Link 8 (br-b57ce470a7a5):
    Link 9 (docker0):
    Link 10 (br-366dd99965dd):
    Link 13 (tun0): 10.22.22.1 10.22.22.2
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is this an office/work VPN or retail customer VPN? Does it work with a direct Ethernet connection between your laptop and your home router? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1486839/edit) and add all these information in your question.

Comment: Thank you. There is a good point to test it via Ethernet cable. I will plan to buy it.

Comment: Please add the output of the command `resolvectl dns` before and after connecting to the VPN. This will tell us which DNS server the computer uses while (**not**) connected to the VPN.

Comment: Sure. 81.95.225.252 81.95.225.253 there are dns servers from my router provider's router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking of VPNs, whenever I'm in the weird situation where "something works but something doesn't" it's often the MTU.
Google services access troubles happened to me for this exact reason.

The Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) is the maximum size of a single data packet that can be transmitted over a network without fragmentation. In the context of OpenVPN and Linux, understanding and properly configuring the MTU is crucial for optimizing network performance and avoiding packet fragmentation.

Here's a description of OpenVPN MTU and how to tweak it under Linux:

1. **MTU and Packet Size**:

The MTU is measured in bytes and represents the largest packet size that can be transmitted over a network without being broken down into smaller fragments.
Larger MTU values allow for more efficient data transmission because fewer packets are required to transmit the same amount of data.
However, if the MTU is set too high and exceeds the capabilities of any network device along the transmission path, fragmentation may occur, leading to performance issues or packet loss.

2. **OpenVPN and MTU**:

OpenVPN operates by encapsulating data within its own packets, which have their own MTU.
By default, OpenVPN sets an MTU of 1500 bytes, which is the standard MTU for Ethernet networks.
The default MTU may not always be suitable for all network configurations, and tweaking it can be necessary to ensure optimal performance.

3. **Tweaking OpenVPN MTU under Linux**:

To adjust the MTU settings for OpenVPN under Linux, you can follow these steps:

a. *Client-Side MTU Setting*:

- On the client-side (the computer connecting to the VPN), you can modify the OpenVPN client configuration file (typically .conf or .ovpn) to set the MTU using the mssfix option.
- For example, add the following line to your client configuration file:
  mssfix 1400 - This reduces the Maximum Segment Size (MSS) to 1400 bytes, which can help avoid fragmentation.

b. *Server-Side MTU Setting*:

- On the server-side (the VPN server), you can modify the OpenVPN server configuration file to set the MTU using the tun-mtu option.
- For example, add the following line to your server configuration file:
  tun-mtu 1400

c. *Path MTU Discovery (PMTUD)*:

- Enabling Path MTU Discovery (PMTUD) can allow endpoints to dynamically adjust the MTU based on the path conditions. You can enable this by adding the following lines to your OpenVPN server and client configurations:
  fragment 1300 mssfix 1300 - This instructs OpenVPN to attempt reducing the MTU to 1300 bytes if issues are encountered.

d. *Testing and Adjusting*:

- It's important to test your MTU settings on your specific network conditions. Start with a conservative value (e.g., 1400) and gradually increase it while monitoring for any issues.

e. *Troubleshooting*:

- If problems persist, consider examining network devices, firewalls, or routers along the network path that may have MTU limitations. Adjust the MTU on these devices if necessary.

By tweaking the MTU settings in your OpenVPN configurations, you can optimize your VPN connections for your specific network environment and reduce potential issues related to packet fragmentation and loss.

---

Uncommon possible cause: your home network provides IPv6 connectivity and your VPN doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to modify my client mtu configuration. I think I can't ask admin to change mtu on server, because it's only my problem, and company doesn't support linux. Also I tried to disable ipv6 on my Linux client, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: It works. After several configuration steps I found the ideal combination for me:
tun-mtu 1350
mssfix 1300

As a result that vpn under my machine is usable. And this comment I writing under vpn.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. And this issue occurred out of nowhere one day.
From my tests, I've come to the conclusion that the issue is with UDP traffic with Wireguard or OpenVPN on Ubuntu.
My VPN provider suggested to try one of these things (they solve this problem):

1. Lowering MTU/MSS.
2. Using TCP.
3. Using WireGuard obfuscation.